# Using batch requests on retrained inception

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to use batch requests on a retrained Inception model using `retrain.py` from tensorflow(actually available on hub repository). Unfortunately I didn't find any documentation available.

Basically I'm using `inception_client.py` to perform requests to `tensorflow_model_server` on a docker container and it works very well when there is one image(even if with the parameter `--enable_batching`). I've tried to use a stacked list of 10 images using `tf.stack()` to test batching but it raises the following exception:

> AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="Input to reshape is a tensor with 20480 values, but the requested shape has 2048 [[Node: pool_3/_reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _output_shapes=[[1,2048]], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](pool_3, pool_3/_reshape/shape)]]")

I'm guessing that my model didn't support batching requests. So, how do I should retrain Inception models to support batching requests?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of batching:
https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_advanced

Try going through that tutorial first, it should hopefully answer some questions.